# Azure Data Factory: what happens if Self-Hosted IR is down

Tags: azure-data-factory

Let's say we need to maintain and reboot a Self-Hosted Integration Runtime machine. We only have one node. At the same, some pipelines may be running. What will happen with activities that are normally scheduled on this SHIR. Will they fail immediately once it's not available, or will they remain in the "waiting" state up to their maximum Timeout value, until a runtime comes back up?

I'd assume it's the latter but wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick try out by stopping the Self-hosted IR service.
[image]

In ADF, the test connection from linked services return error:
[image]

Copy activity that involves the self-hosted IR failed immediately:
[image]

Comment: Sure, did that. Thank you again